# Will a search engine index links with different languages if all apart from the main page are missing the path?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engines, search-engine-indexing, language

Our website `www.websitename.com` has three languages

E.g:

`www.websitename.com/it`

`www.websitename.com/en`

`www.websitename.com/fr`

by going to each of those links you will get all the remaining pages in the selected language.

You can also visit a page by manually typing the sub-folder at the front and automatically change the language : `e.g www.websitename/en/test.php.`

However by default apart from the main page e.g `www.websitename.com/en` the rest of the pages won't have the sub-folder appended to the URL so the links will be  `www.websitename/test1.php, www.websitename/test2.php` etc.

Will Google or other search engine index the different of those or it will be only one version indexed because they are missing the language in the path?

Comment: Are these pages all separate pages, or are you using cookies to translate a single page into 3 languages?

Comment: they are the same page (with different content/language using text files) I am using session vars.

Answer (score 2):

If the pages are all the same and the language is dynamically changing Google wont be able to crawl the different languages.

When structuring a multi-lingual site, each language must be on separate URLs which Google can easily discover and crawl:

As Google explains:

> Make sure each language version is easily discoverable
>
> Keep the content for each language on separate URLs. Don’t use cookies
>   to show translated versions of the page. Consider cross-linking each
>   language version of a page. That way, a French user who lands on the
>   German version of your page can get to the right language version with
>   a single click.
>
> Avoid automatic redirection based on the user’s perceived language.
>   These redirections could prevent users (and search engines) from
>   viewing all the versions of your site.

The recommended structure is using either sub domains, or sub folders, like you already have - But each language must have its seperate page within the sub folders.

More info can be found from Google here: [Multi-regional and multilingual sites](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en&ref_topic=2370587)

Answer (score 0):

To follow on from @moobot's answer...

The correct way to handle what you're trying to achieve is to serve `rel="alternate" hreflang="x"` listing all the variations of the same page for different locations/languages in the `<head>` on a page. And also including the original version as well in the event there is not a version for a specific language/location so Google knows what to show by default.

You can learn more about this at [Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en).